# Add a value if this value doesn't exist in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a default dictionary. I loop through many strings and add them to the directory under the key as a number but only if there is no that value already in dictionary. So my code looks like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
strings = ["val1", "val2", "val2", "val3"]
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

key = 0
for string in strings:
    if string not in my_dict.itervalues():
        my_dict[key].append(string)
        key += 1

print my_dict
```

but it seems not to work because all of strings are added to the dictionary, like this:

`defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['val1'], 1: ['val2'], 2: ['val2'], 3: ['val3']})`

'val2' shouldn't be added and it should looks like this:

`defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['val1'], 1: ['val2'], 2: ['val3']})`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest playing around with simpler examples. Try to guess the results of these expressions:`1 in [1]` and `1 in [[1]]` and `[1] in [[1]]`. If you can identify a pattern, you can apply this knowledge to your actual problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in the end, and why you're using defaultdict for it. How about `dedup = set(strings)` to remove duplicated then `dict(zip(range(len(dedup)),dedup))` to make the list a dictionary?

Comment: Thank you @Kevin, now I see how it works

Comment: @raphv, I used the list here just to simplify my code and show only the problem. In my whole code I iterate through many files and I don't keep values in lists to save RAM memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `my_dict.itervalues()` returns a list of lists in your case. So `string not in lists` always returns `True`, as you can see from the following code,

```
>>> "val2" not in [["val1"], ["val2"]]
True
```

To get the desired result, flat a list of lists into a list using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable),

```
>>> import itertools
>>> "val2" not in itertools.chain.from_iterable([["val1"], ["val2"]])
False
```

---

The full source code for your case,

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

strings = ["val1", "val2", "val2", "val3"]
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

key = 0
for string in strings:
    if string not in itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()): # flat a list of lists into a list
        my_dict[key].append(string)
        key += 1

print(my_dict)
# Output
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['val1'], 1: ['val2'], 2: ['val3']})
```